# Perl - from JSON to object/ hash

Tags: json, perl

I have to code below:

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;

my $json = '{"Object1":{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q3","DataType":"Other 3","Environment":"STEVE","Amount":125},"Object2":{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q4","DataType":"Other 2","Environment":"MIKE","Amount":500}}';

my $arrayref = decode_json $json;

for my $array(@$arrayref){
        for my $key (keys(%$array)){
                my $val = $array->{$key};
                print "$key: $val\n";
        }

}
```

When I compile it, it print me the error "Not an ARRAY reference at generator.pl line 12.".

I want to parse the JSON to an object and get data according to the object with the attributes. How can I do it?

I expect after I parse it, I can use to compare string, print, loop it and so on.

Comment: It's a hashref.  You can discover that by `ref` builtin. Or print the whole thing by one of the number of modules for working with complex data structure, `Data::Dumper` for example.

Comment: I don't know what it will return, since there is more than one values and attributes, so I will expect it in array form, so I might print in form of array[0].Year, array[1].Quarter...something like that, or if not, how can I use the value in hash?

Comment: @zdim how could I use that?

Comment: The `ref`tells you whether it is `HASH` or `ARRAY` (or other) or not a reference -- see docs for `ref`.  The top-level is probably going to be hashref (this is not strictly required), and in your case that's just what you have. Then you iterate over `keys %$hashref` (what you call `$arrayref`). Or, `use Data::Dumper; print  Dumper $reference;` to see the whole thing that is in `$reference`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no arrays there; it is a hash of hashes.

```
my $hashref = decode_json $json;

for my $object_name (sort keys %$hashref){
        print "In $object_name:\n";
        for my $key (sort keys %{ $hashref->{$object_name} }){
                my $val = $hashref->{$object_name}{$key};
                print "$key: $val\n";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not array reference, it is hash reference:

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = '{"Object1":{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q3","DataType":"Other 3","Environment":"STEVE","Amount":125},"Object2":{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q4","DataType":"Other 2","Environment":"MIKE","Amount":500}}';

my $arrayref = decode_json $json;

print Data::Dumper->Dump([$arrayref], [qw(arrayref)]);
```

And output:

```
$arrayref = {
              'Object2' => {
                             'Quarter' => 'Q4',
                             'Year' => '2012',
                             'Amount' => 500,
                             'DataType' => 'Other 2',
                             'Environment' => 'MIKE'
                           },
              'Object1' => {
                             'Amount' => 125,
                             'DataType' => 'Other 3',
                             'Year' => '2012',
                             'Environment' => 'STEVE',
                             'Quarter' => 'Q3'
                           }
            };
```